# Cuda math functions

Tags: cuda

I'm trying to use the floor() function inside a cuda kernel, but I always get the following error :
    calling a **host** function("floor ") from a **global** function(" ") is not allowed.

I also included the cuda "math_functions.h", so what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're probably mismatching the type of the argument and thus calling a host code function as a "fallback mechanism".

Make sure you're using the right type for the function (which is **not** float, but double: http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/).

Also note [the documentation stating](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-math-api/group__CUDA__MATH__DOUBLE.html)

> To use these functions you do not need to include any additional header files in your program.

Comment: In the documentation, it is precised that no header has to be added. Maybe your answer could add this information.